# How can I remove small check boxes left side on the list box based on CCheckListBox?

Tags: mfc

I use **CCheckListBox** instead of **CListBox**, but I want to remove check boxes to only remain strings like a list box based on **CListBox**.
If it's not possible, I want to know the way making disable an individual items in the list box based on **CListBox**.

Comment: If you don't want checkboxes for items in a listbox control, don't use a `CCheckListBox`. Use a `CListBox` instead. Why do you think that this isn't a solution to your problem? Incidentally, what **is** the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable If I click an item in the list box, then I want to make the other items in the list box disabled. But making items disable is only possible with CCheckListBox. But I don't want to make the check boxes on the left in check list box. What should I do?

Comment: A list box is a list of items, that allows zero, one, or more items to be selected. Why do you believe that unselected items must be disabled? And how would you select one of those disabled items, in case you change your mind? You surely are trying hard to give your users the most unpleasant user experience possible. Use the list box the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, if the user click an input item, then only input items should be selected, which means output items in the same list box should be disabled. That's the way I want to make.

Comment: Have you thought this through? What if the user changes her mind halfway through and now wants to select *output* items instead of the *input* items initially selected. She can't, because those have been disabled. You are trying hard to implement a really, REALLY bad user experience. Instead of restricting what a user can do, validate the input.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, that's true. So, I made the add button which is disable when someone tries to add input and output both, instead of hiding the input or output items. Anyway, thanks a lot, I changed my mind because of your comment.